# Sharing information about apps built with ArcGIS API for JavaScript?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I built an app with the ArcGIS Javascript API and made it available on GitHub.

Where would be an appropriate place to tell GIS users/developers about it?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  In a moment I will try to provide an Answer to your Question but in the meantime I have removed the link to your app on GitHub because it was effectively an advertisement for your work.

Comment: BTW +1 Although here is not the place to share I think it is a good place to ask about where to share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try twitter - there's an active community of Esri JavaScript developers. I've created a (somewhat) maintained list here:

https://twitter.com/tomwayson/lists/esrijs

Some tips about sharing:

- Make sure you have a good README that explains what the app does,
  what problem it solves, and how developers can get install/use it
- It's best if you can include a live link to the app so people can see
  how it's supposed to work

If you have your own blog, that's a good place to make a post on the back story behind the app, why you developed it, etc (as opposed to the GitHub README, which should be focused on the 'what' and 'how').

Comment: Thanks for the info. Are you sure that twitter link is right? I keep getting "page not found."

Comment: Hm... the list is shared publicly, and I asked a colleague to try the link and it worked for them. Can't figure out why it doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 0):

In a **[blog posting](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2008/07/28/showcase-your-arcgis-server-application-in-the-code-gallery/)**, now almost 6 years old, Esri advertised its **[ArcGIS JavaScript Code Gallery](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/help/gallery.html)** as being the place to do this.

> The code gallery is a place where you can highlight your work

However, if you try to follow that link you will get:

> Page Not Found

I thought its replacement page might be **[here](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/)** but that seems to be a page only for Esri's own samples.